# passing core data object without saving

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

I'm trying to pass core data object from one controller to another without saving the changes. but I'm getting CoreData: error: Mutating a managed object 0x14f70f510

Here's the code:

```
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
Item *item  = [Item MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
item.code = indexPath.row;

NextController *controller = [[NextController alloc] initWithItem:item];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

The reason why I don't want to save the data right away because I want to wait until the user finished the process of creating the new item.

Comment: save right away and put a flag in there saying it is complete, it will be much easier, you can move NSManagedObjects around, but it is a pain

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make a call to perform a segue when you select an item

```
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:sender];

}
```

Create the NSManagedObject and pass it to the view controller you're pushing to.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) { 
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
        Item *item  = [Item MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
        item.code = path.row;

        CustomViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController]
        [vc theNameOfTheNSManagedObjectInTheVCYouPushTo: item]
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboard so I can't do this. 

I tried NextController *controller = [[NextController alloc] init];
controller.item = item;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

but it's still giving me the core data error.

Answer (score 0):

Save it after every whole operation, which is recommended by [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/Docs/Saving-Entities.md), because your app may crash or terminated by user at any time.
One more thing, `[item MR_inContext:localContext]` will obtain the Permanent Object ID for the item. This may be helpful.

Comment: thanks, but my point of passing it without saving is that I don't want to store unnecessary data. I only want to save it when the user completed the whole flow. I can do this with creating regular object but since I already have the data model with core data, it seems redundant to do it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new entity in localContext and if you want to do something with it you should also pass this localContext as your parameter.

I mean next:

```
NextController *controller = [[NextController alloc] initWithItem:item];
```

use as:

```
NextController *controller = [[NextController alloc] initWithItem:item yourLocalContext:localContext];
```

In this case you can change your *item*.